# Windows capture graphic output of a process?

Tags: java, windows, powershell, process, directx

Here the situation, I have a computer without a monitor let's say **computer1** and a second computer with a monitor let's say **computer2**. (both **Windows**)

I will launch a `.bat` on **computer1** from **computer2** that will run `minecraft.exe`

First step I wanted to know if it was possible to capture the graphic output of the minecraft process with a program in `c# copyFromScreen`, `java robot api` or a powershell script on **computer1**.
Since it does not have a monitor and so an active window, I guess that the first two options are not possible?

Second step after capturing the graphic data flux I wanted to try to redirect it to **computer2** and try to display what I get but here I have no idea how to do that, since it depends on first step.

Any suggested method or API to achieve that?

Comment: Any reason why you can't or don't want to RDP / MSTSC to computer1 from from computer2?

Comment: I don't what it is, what would be the goal of RDP / MSTSC in my case?

Comment: RDP (mstsc.exe) allows you to connect to a remote machine (computer1), and it displays windows as if it is on your computer (computer2). It allows both audio and video. Caveat is, it uses it's own display drivers - So YMMV with graphically intensive programs. I _believe_ mstsc is available on all Windows installations, just go to the run dialog and type `mstsc` or create a shortcut to `C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe`. You will likely need to set up computer1 to enable remote desktop: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17463/windows-7-connect-to-another-computer-remote-desktop-connection

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. So I guess it means that it is possible; But I still have no idea how to do it myself programmatically

Comment: If you have windows 10 pro or higher you just run remote desktop and put in the other machines name or IP. And then the credentials. And it will sort of be like running a virtual machine. No programming required.

Comment: I understood I will try it out. But if I still want to do it programmatically focusing only  minecraft process and not the whole computer desktop do you methods API that could help ?